# Xcode - search text in all files

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to search through all Xcode project files? I know that I can find some text inside file with finder, but finding something with Xcode will be very helpful. When I press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> I can only ***find*** or ***find and replace*** in current display file.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Use  <kbd>cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> for complete Xcode search.

Comment: Is there a way to make search ignore certain directories in the workspace? In particular, I'm usually not interested in searching the Pods directory.

Comment: @august - check my answer in this post -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603639/exclude-a-file-from-xcode-when-searching/24603846#24603846

Comment: Using cmd  + shift + f  will search in code only, how to search also in "comments" and "string const" ?

Comment: Hi Gil, there's actually a menu for it. Once you hit CMD+Shift+F, look for Find > Reference > Containing right above the text box. Click on "Reference" and change it to "Text". This will search for every piece of text.

Comment: This is still not searching in "Pos"

Comment: This will not search any dependent repos, such as Swift Packages.

Answer (score 17):

## To do it simply from the UI, with a click

By default, this will be searching through the entire project searching for any files containing the specific string you entered.

[image]

## From this point, you can start doing more stuffs like replace all, etc, like this

[image]

Comment: Great animated .gif's to show the answer, what tool did you use to generate those?

Answer (score 16):

On the left hand side of the editor you have a magnifying glass. There's a search box there. That should do the trick. (it's called the `search navigator`)

`cmd + shift + f` opens it too.

Comment: Or from the menu: `Find > Find in Project`.

Comment: Called Find > Find in Workspace now?

Answer (score 3):

cmd + shift + f

then press return key of you keyboard.

Comment: return key goes multiline instead of executing search.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Command + 3` a minimum keyboard shortcut
or `Command + Shift + f`

Answer (score 0):

In find use: Find > Text > Containing

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on any text and select 'Find Selected Text in Workspace'

In my experience,  **cmd  + shift + f** requires **cmd  + c** before hand to populate the search term. So, my go to search for text in all files is to do the above.