# Exclude a file from Xcode when searching

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Is it possible to exclude files in a project from Xcode when searching?  I have some JSON files in my project and Xcode constantly locks up if it finds matches in these files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define custom search scope for your search.  Custom scope can be define, save, and reuse specific location and file criteria for searches.
[image]

Now you can add as as many file names as you want.
[image]

More details on how to use custom search scope can be found here- https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-search_navigator/articles/adding_a_search_scope.html

Comment: Awesome!  I never knew that text below the search field was a button.  So many hidden features like this in Xcode.

Comment: @BerryBlue That's what happens when Apple ignores its own HIG (Human Interface Guidelines)... A proper Mac application (Xcode should be...) must have ALL its functionality available from the menu-bar. Buttons only serve as time-saving short-cuts. So, when I receive a new app, or a new version - all I do is simply browse the menus and look for interesting stuff.

Answer (score 3):

## Xcode 9 update

Here are examples to search including or excluding file names, file extensions, etc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefere to use regexp.
example for excluding unit tests files "foo_unittest.cc" or "foo_test.m"

```
^.((?!test).)*$
```

dropdown fields conditions:

- "File name"
- "matches regular expression"