# ERROR ITMS-90190: "The key 'UISupportedDevices' in the Info.plist file is not valid."

Tags: ios, application-loader

Im trying to upload my first app through Application Loader and Im getting this error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90190: "Invalid Info.plist Key. The key 'UISupportedDevices' in the Info.plist file is not valid."
```

I have no idea what it means and I can't find info or support in Apple documentation

My app has also an Apple Watch application target

> Solved, It seems to be a problem with Apple's servers. They answered
>   me now it's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, It seems to be a problem with Apple's servers. They answered me now it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Xcode 7. Do this.

- make a backup of your info.plist file
- open you info.plist file with TextEdit
- Find xml node for UISupportedDevices
- remove that entire node and save
- Then do clean, build, re-archive and upload

I checked and there should not be any value called UISupportedDevices in your plist file. At least there isn't one if you create a brand new project in Xcode 7

Comment: The thing is I have checked I don't have any "UISupportedDevices" node in my info.plist....I don't know why app loader is showing me this error. My project was created in Xcode 6 I think...But it's compiling and everything's working. :/ (And yes, Im using Xcode 7.2.1)

Comment: Yes, everything will work except when it comes time to upload your binary to itunes. That's when it will complain. In one of your info.plist files in your project there is a value set. If you think its not then delete everything in your derived data folder, do build clean and try upload again

Comment: Search for UISupportedDevices in all files - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583099/xcode-search-text-in-all-files

Comment: Yes, I have also searched all the project through Xcode looking for "'UISupportedDevices" but I got anything... I have tried deleting derived data folder and building again but same error :(